# s/old/new syntax regex replacement in Python

Tags: python, regex, sed, awk

I'm writing something in Python and I **require** a `s/old/new/flags`-style regular expression replacement method for Python, **with** that syntax. Is this something that Python provides, without me having to call sed or something?

Thanks.

Comment: That's an odd requirement. Can you explain why you need it? You could probably write a helper that parses that syntax and calls `re.sub`.

Comment: Sed's regexen are different than python's as well. But python's re modules takes flags, it shouldn't be too hard to whip this together on your own.

Comment: You **require** the syntax to exist? wow

Comment: Syntax isn't usually a requirement. It's like saying, "I **require** the ability to use `&&` for `and`," or "I **require** reverse Polish notation for my math expressions." Are you reading regexes from input or something?

Comment: I require the syntax because I'm taking in input. I should've been more clear, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

No. Python provides this behavior through the `re.sub` function or the equivalent method on compiled regexp objects, but does not use the sed-style syntax.

Comment: That works, I can just roll my own to get the syntax I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Peter, you can use `re.sub`.

The syntax is as follows: `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

More information on that method here: [re — Regular expression operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)